# `npm link` inside a monorepo adds the dependency always to the root

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, monorepo

I have a mono repo and want to link a component library inside a package which contains this library as a dependency. But as we control this library and make changes, I want to be able to test it locally.

```
cd <library_path>
npm link
cd <monorepo_path>
npm link --workspace <target_package> <library>
```

When I execute find: `find -name '<library>'` I can find the library in the `<target_package>` `node_modules` directory as well as in the roots `node_modules` directory, which means the one in the `<target_package>` will take precedence, but this is the published one, not the linked one. The linked one lives in the root.

When I install my `node_modules` without linking the package, the library lives only inside the root `node_modules`.

I tried several things without success.

How can I override the workspace dependency temporarily to use the local library from `npm link`?

EDIT:

I found a temporary workaround in our webpack configuration with hardcoding which path to use for this dependency.
However, this is not a satisfying solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem that you have and found out that it is actually a documented "feature".

> `npm link <pkg> --workspace <name>` will link the relevant package as a dependency of the specified workspace(s). Note that It may actually be linked into the parent project's `node_modules` folder, if there are no conflicting dependencies.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link#workspace-usage

You can try using alternative solutions to `npm link` such as `yalc`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34933166)

Comment: That's a good point, thanks! I added the quote.